# How to reference a pictureBox in another Form (Changing a PictureBox from another Form)

Tags: c#, image, winforms, picturebox

I have been building my application with 2 forms, a Home one and a separate form meant at displaying the image. It uses an OpenFileDialog and filters out files for selection. However, how do I actually reference the the Picture Box on the other Form itself?

```
// open file dialog   
OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();  
// image filters  
open.Filter = "Image Files(*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp)|*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp";  
if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {  
    // display image in picture box  

    // How to change this to access pictureBox1 on Form2
    pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(open.FileName);
```

The script above is executed by button. Once again how to reference pictureBox from Form2?

Answer (score 0):

If your picture box sits on another form, you just give it a "internal" access and  manipulate it in the instance of that form

```
var f = new PicForm();
f.picBox.Image = ....
f.Show();
```

But even better if you make your picture form self - contained. Add constructor parameter

```
public PicForm (string path) : base()
{
    if (File.Exists(path)) 
        this.picBox.Image = new Bitmap(path);
}
```